# Repeated values when trying to Insert a row using the .insert()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file I'm trying to make lists from. The txt file has 3 columns tab separated (index, word, tag).

Example of the txt file:

```
1   i   PRP
2   want    VBP
3   to  TO
4   go  VB
```

What I'm trying to do is add a beginning and end of sentence marker (`<s>` for beginning and `</s>` for the end).

My code is as follows:

```
trainfile=open("/Users/Desktop/training.txt").read().split('\n')
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

trainlines=[]

for line in trainfile:
    trainlines.append(line)

indexlist=[]
wordlist=[]
taglist=[]

word_tag_counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for line in trainlines:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    index, word, tags = line.split()
    word_tag_counts[word.lower()][tags] += 1
    indexlist.append(index)
    if index == "1":
        indexlist.insert(0, '0')
        wordlist.insert(0, '<s>')
        taglist.insert(0, '<s>')
    else:
        indexlist.append(index)
        wordlist.append(word)
        taglist.append(tags)
        if word == '.':
            taglist.append('</s>')
            wordlist.append('</s>')
        else:
            continue
```

The issue I'm having is my results for the indexlist are:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',...]
```

and wordlist and taglist are the same problem:

```
['<s>', '<s>', '<s>', '<s>', '<s>', '<s>', '<s>', '<s>', '<s>',...]
```

Why is the inserted property the only thing thats showing up in my entire list?

What I want for a final result is:

```
indexlist: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2...]
wordlist: [<s>, i, want, to, go, home, </s>, <s>, ...]
```

Comment: `for line in trainfile:
    trainlines.append(line)` is the same as `trainlines = trainfile[:]`

Comment: oh sweet, thanks! thats a much better way. appreciate it.

Comment: I tried your script. I get `indexlist = ['0', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4'] wordlist =  ['<s>', 'want', 'to', 'go'] taglist =  ['<s>', 'VBP', 'TO', 'VB']`

Comment: It's also not clear why you need both variables `trainfile` and `trainlines`.

Comment: I'm doing a lot more in this code than what I'm showing above. The train file is the file I'm obtaining all of my data from but later i'm editing the lines and changing whats in them. I don't want to edit the actual information in the file or have to keep calling to the file.

Comment: I get the same results as @Barmar did from your code. Would you please [edit] your question and add explanations of exactly what information is in each of the lists. That ought to make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: You only append `</s>` when the file has `word = .`, but that's not in the sample file you showed.